# PubNub client() function not working for callbacks

Tags: objective-c, swift, pubnub

Currently in Swift I have a PubNub object subscribed to a specific channel. Whenever an event happens, I can see a Logger instance being done, however none of the client() functions are receiving anything as callbacks.

The three I have set up are:

```
    func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveStatus status: PNSubscribeStatus!) 
    func client(client: PubNub!, didReceivePresenceEvent event: PNPresenceEventResult!)
    func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult!, withStatus status: PNErrorStatus!)
```

Is there another way to receive the subscription event callback or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Howdy there `Min Tseng`.  This issue may be as simple as a channel or API Key mismatch.  You mentioned that the debug output shows logging events occurring.  Are those events messages being received?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call *addListener(self)* on **PubNub** instance passing required instance instead of *self* which conform to **PNObjectEventListener** protocol.